# How to negate conditional validation in TYPO3>Typoscript>Formhandler?

Tags: forms, typo3, typoscript

I would like to check whether a field has a value other than "MasterValue". is it true then it must be another field tested for the validation.

But the assignment operator "!=" does not work. With "=" it works and show the required field message.

Typoscript:

```
if {
    1 {
        conditions {
            OR1.AND1 = nationality!=MasterValue
        }
        isTrue {
            validators.1.config.fieldConf {
                residence_permit {
                    errorCheck.1 = required                                     
                }
            }
        }

    }
} # if
```

Versions: TYPO3 4.5.2, Formhandler 0.9.12

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you hit a bug there: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/6430

This is fixed in 1.0.0, consider upgrading formhandler.